# how to get “appendices” horizontally centered?

Tags: appendices

I am using the article class, and when using `\begin{appendices}` `\end{appendices}`, the "Appendices" header is automatically aligned to the left.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make it horizontally centered? Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What do you want it to be vertically centred in relation to? Do you want it to be on a page of its own so that the first appendix starts on a new page?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: i think you really mean *horizontally* centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}   %% just for demo
\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix}

\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\centering Appendices}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
 \section{Appendix here}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh. *Horizontally* centred?

Comment: @cfr Think so. Because in article class, there is no separate appendix page.

Comment: That's what was confusing me. You are probably right.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want. I just want "Appendices" centered, and the line you gave---\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\centering Appendices}---is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: sorry HK I haven't got a reputation score of 15 so cannot vote you up, but I will come back to do so once i get to 15.